# Printing from a Linux using an Acer Aspire Netbook

Tags: linux, printing, acer-aspire

A friend asked me to check why their Linux Acer Aspire netbook can't print to their HP printer.   When I plugged in the USB cable, the a "balloon" popped up on the netbook saying it was installing the printer.  But the printing does not work.  I was able to get into a Settings area and click on Print Test Page but nothing happened.

If it was Ubuntu, I would go into the Log File Viewer, but I couldn't find that on whatever Linux flavor the Acer is running.  I couldn't even figure out how to get to a terminal (shell) window.  I tried searching the HP and Acer sites but nothing seems to apply to this issue.

Comment: What was the model of the printer?

Comment: The model was hp 5610

Comment: The execute any command, you can use Alt+F2. BTW, you'll probably want to run `xfce-setting-show`, and enable "Show desktop menu on right click" to get better access to the system.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to install the "hplip" and try to get the printer to work with that.

That printer seem to be supported with hplip:

- http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/models/officejet/officejet_5600_series.html

Answer (score 0):

The [OpenPrinting](http://www.openprinting.org/printer_list.cgi) site maintains the current  status of printer compatibility on linux. Check if you can find your friend's printer on this [list of HP printers](http://www.openprinting.org/printer_list.cgi?make=HP). You can also look at the related [Foomatic](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/en/OpenPrinting/Database/Foomatic) system for integrating free software printer drivers on linux.

The [linux Acer Aspire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspire_One#Linux) comes pre-installed with the Fedora 8 based [Linpus Lite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linpus_Linux) Linux distribution.

Comment: I found this link there... http://www.openprinting.org/show_printer.cgi?recnum=HP-OfficeJet_5600 I'll try it when I go back to her house.  But how to I get a terminal window on the Aspire?

Comment: Read this article: http://www.laptopmag.com/advice/how-to/aspire-one-apps.aspx The first step tells you how to bring up the terminal window. Read the remainder if you'd like to tweak the OS some more.